# Is there a way to update or merge string literals with kustomize?

Tags: kustomize, argocd

I'm trying to manage Argo CD projects with helm definitions using kustomize.

Unfortunately Argo manages helm values with string literals, which gives me headaches in conjunction with kustomize configuration.

I have this base/application.yml

```
apiVersion: argoproj.io/v1alpha1
kind: Application
  source:
    chart: something
    helm:
      values: |
        storageClass: cinder-csi
        ... many more lines identical to every stage
```

and I'd like to create variants using kustomize overlays, where I'd like to add a single line solely important for the dev stage to the base values.

This is NOT working, it simply replaces the existing base definiton.

overlay/dev/kustomize.yml

```
apiVersion: kustomize.config.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: Kustomization

patchesJson6902:
- target:
    kind: Application
  patch: |-
    - op: add
      path: /source/helm/value
      value: "storageSize: 1Gi"
```

To me it seems kustomize can not append values to string literals. My current solution requires to repeat the whole values string literal in every stage variant, with just a few lines of difference, which heavily violates DRY principles.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's an [open PR](https://github.com/argoproj/argo-cd/pull/8794) to add support for arbitrary YAML in the `values` field. If merged, I would expect it to be available in 2.4. Reviews/testing are appreciated if you have time!

One workaround is to use the [`parameters` field](https://github.com/argoproj/argo-cd/blob/a6c664b2aefc513936e9f56c1a373bdbddcd5727/docs/operator-manual/application.yaml#L24) and set parameters individually. It's not ideal, but maybe could help until 2.4 is released.

Comment: That PR was closed, worked moved to another PR, which closed and moved to https://github.com/argoproj/argo-cd/pull/11538, which is still not merged and was just recently *removed* from argo 2.7 milestone.

Comment: @JonL. yep. It will happen, just a matter of review resources right now.

Answer (score 1):

For future reference, 3 days ago a PR was finally merged:
https://github.com/argoproj/argo-cd/pull/11538

as of writing this, no release yet, but it's on master branch